# Coverity analysis shows error with const type. How to resolve this?

Tags: c++, constants, coverity, coverity-prevent

When I am running Coverity analysis shows error in function below.

```cpp
void initalizeStatement(sqlite3* db, const char* query)
{
    // statement shall not be reuesed!
    if (_valid) _valid = false;
    else
    {
        sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;
        auto result = sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL);

        if(SQLITE_OK != result)
        {
            DLT_LOG(dltContextSARMBUtils, DLT_LOG_ERROR,
                   DLT_STRING("[Statement::initalizeStatement()] sqlite3_prepare failed. status code : "),
                   DLT_INT(result),
                   DLT_STRING(", query : "),
                   DLT_STRING(query));
        }

        else //all good!
        {
            _valid = true;
            _stmt = stmt;
            _db = db;
        }
    }
}
```

Error I am seeing is as below:

```xml
<testcase name="[45] MISRA C++-2008 Rule 7-1-1 | misra_cpp_2008_rule_7_1_1_violation" time="0">
<failure message="The variable `query` has a non-const type, however its value is never changed. Consider adding a const qualifier to the variable type."> MBUtils::Statement::initalizeStatement(sqlite3*, char const*) </failure>
```

Why is this error shown if it is already having `const` type?

Comment: I suppost it wants `void initalizeStatement(sqlite3* db, const char* const query);`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: Add const to the declaration

MISRA C++ 2008 Rule 7-1-1 reads, in its entirety, "A variable which is not modified shall be const qualified."  (The standard is not freely available so I can't link to it.)  Additionally, the example given in the standard makes it clear that this rule applies to parameters as well as local variables.

In your example code, `query` is not modified, hence it must be `const` qualified to comply with this rule:

```
void initalizeStatement(sqlite3* db, const char* const query)
//                                               ^^^^^ added
```

In your original code, `query` is declared to *point* to something that is `const`, but is not itself `const`.

### How to read C declarations

As the syntax for C/C++ declarations can be a bit confusing, my advice is to read them from right to left.  So the original declaration:

```
const char * query
```

would be read as "query is a pointer to a character that is constant".  The declaration in my suggested fix:

```
const char * const query
```

would be read as "query is a constant pointer to a character that is constant".

### Style opinion

Incidentally, if this were my code (and I had to comply with MISRA), I would actually write it as:

```
char const * const query
```

This reverses the order of `char` and `const` at the beginning, so it now reads as "query is a constant pointer to a constant character", which is a more natural English description.